# Windows Explorer style view of simple hierarchical data

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to display a simple "list of lists" on a WPF form where, for each parent row, the children are displayed in a horizontal wrappanel - could someone please help with required XAML?

e.g.
Hierarchical data such as:

```
class Parent { public string Key; public List<Child> Children; }
class Child { public string Name; }
```

The desired display would be (K/Key, N/Name):

```
|K1    N1 N2 N3|
|      N4 N5   |
|K2    N1 N2   |
```

I'm fairly new to WPF, I tried things like:

```
<ListView Name="lv" Binding="myParentList">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding myParentListItems}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </WrapPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
<ListView Name="lv" Binding="myParentList">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding myParentListItems}">
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                            </WrapPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <Template>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Template>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: This is great - thanks! Works great using the "ItemsPanel" definition. One minor thing- if you get a chance, please edit your answer to include a "DataTemplate" tag to wrap "<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />" - I got an error without this. BTW it says I have to wait 14 hours to award bounty. Will do so ASAP. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot the Template tag.